# Will the install create a dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot

Ok, I picked up an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS disk.  I currently have 4T of storage, and an SSD 250g with Windows on it.  I am not using Win 10.  If I install the Linux disk, will it automatically create a dual boot upon start up, or will it erase my Windows files?  I think I need Windows (ugh) for a couple games I play on FB (Trainstation and Seaport.)  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will create a dual boot, but i recommend that you create a partition on your ssd (split it half linux and half windows), i would also recommend you to create a partition on your hard drive, and use it as your /home, this last one would need to be at least 100 Go or some thing. The live CD installation provides you the tools to do this (choosing advanced install at some point). But be very careful if you don't know what you are doing.

Check on the internet for some more info.